# Kubernetes Deployment Rollback API

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I'm looking for the API used by kubernetes clients to rollback deployments.

I can find that in the older versions of kubernetes API docs
`POST /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/rollback`([reference](https://v1-15.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#rollback-deployment-v1beta1-extensions)) is the API being used. However this documentation seems to have been removed in versions later than 1.18 and I can't seem to find any replacement for this API either in the new documentation.

If the API no longer exists how do clients such as kubectl or any of the client libraries rollback deployments in the newer versions of kubernetes?

Comment: FWIW, running `kubectl` at higher verbosity (likely `--v=3`) will show a "curl-esque" representations of everything it's doing; if you keep increasing the verbosity, it'll also show the data payloads

Comment: I did not know that, thanks a lot for your suggestion :). I had to go up to level 7 to see the apis being called and level 8 showed me the request and response bodies (although truncated versions of them). Turns out that in the newer versions, rollbacks are achieved by doing a PATCH on `/deployments/{deploymentName}`. Exactly how it figures out what to patch is probably an implementation detail but still curious. Would other client sdk packages be affected by this? last i checked, the fabric8 java sdk used the `/rollback` api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing API is an result of the changes made in the newest Kubernetes version 1.19:

> `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1`  is deprecated in favor of
> `apiextensions.k8s.io/v1`
> ([#90673](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/90673),
> [@deads2k](https://github.com/deads2k)) [SIG API Machinery]

As suggested by community running `kubectl` with high verbosity level will allow to debug your commands at high level.  You can check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging) more about verbosity and debugging.